# Default Spring Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, frameworks

I am new to Spring framework......

I want to know by default which auto-wiring way will be used to inject properties value to the class.

As I read I came to know that there is no default autowiring available, so how it is getting autowired in the below case where I didn't mention anything for autowiring.

beans.xml file

```
<bean id="javaLanguage" class="LanguageBean">
<property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
</bean>
```

LanguageBean.java

```
public class LanguageBean implements BeanNameAware
{
private String languageName;
private String beanName;

setter & getter are there.

}
```

When I run the Program i got the value for property name languageName, So by which mechanism it get injected the value, how it came to know to use setter injection and not constructor injection?
Also is Dependency Injection same as Autowiring?
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show more of your beans.xml file? In particular, your root <beans> node?

Comment: beans.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="javaLanguage" class="LanguageBean">
    <property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
</bean>

</beans>

I am not writing any wiring attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first you did inject the value yourself by writing:

```
<property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
```

Using the bean-element you created a new instance of class "LanguageBean" having an instance name "javaLanguage". With the property-element you are injecting the value "Java" into that bean (manually) by filed injection. If you want constructor injection, use the constructor-element instead.

With autowiring you can inject beans or values into other beans automatically. That means you dont explicitly define an injection in your beans.xml. Lets say you have another bean called "AnotherBeanUsingLanguageBean" defined in your context:

```
<bean id="javaLanguage" class="LanguageBean">
    <property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherBean" class="AnotherBeanUsingLanguageBean" />
```

AnotherBeanUsingLanguageBean:

```
public class AnotherBeanUsingLanguageBean {
    @Autowiring
    private LanguageBean languageBean;
}
```

At startup the instance of LanguageBean will automatically be injected into the anotherBean instance. For more information on autowiring have a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Manual injection would look like this:

```
<bean id="javaLanguage" class="LanguageBean">
    <property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherBean" class="AnotherBeanUsingLanguageBean" >
    <property name="languageBean" ref="javaLanguage"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear Explaination, It help me a lot. I got the point now

Answer (score 0):

By default it resolves to 'Setter injection'. So is the reason why you are able to get the values.

Comment: Refer section '3.3.5. Autowiring collaborators' here [Link]: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html

Comment: I read in some article that if you don't provide anything then it will not do anything and instead you have to manually write auto wiring thing using ref attribute,

I am bit confused, can you provide some link containing description on this will be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The default autowire setting is ["no"](http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html), which means you have to explicit wire your dependencies (using either @Autowire or XML-based configuration).

In your case it looks like you have explicitly wired your `languageName` property to "Java" in your XML configuration, this will call your `setLanguageName()` setter with the value "Java" when the Spring bean is created.

Auto-wiring does something different to this. It will implicitly wire dependencies using a strategy you specify. If you set `default-autowire="byType"`, Spring will attempt to autowire your properties using the Class type to determine the best match. So:

```
<beans xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans"; 
       xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; 
       xsi:schemaLocation="springframework.org/schema/beans springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"

       default-autowire="byType"> <!-- Autowire by class type -->

    <!-- NOTE: No property values are set here -->
    <bean id="steering" class="Steering" />
    <bean id="car" class="Car" />
</beans>

public class Steering {
}

public class Car {

    private Steering steeringLogic;

    // This setter will be called by Spring with the "Steering" bean, which is 
    // the best matching class type for the field
    public void setSteeringLogic(Steering steeringLogic) {
        this.steeringLogic = steeringLogic;
    }

}
```

See this article for more information on Spring wiring: http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html

Comment: my beans.xml file is :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">


<bean id="javaLanguage" class="LanguageBean">
    <property name="languageName" value="Java"/>
</bean>

</beans>

So, In these I have  not mention anything that says use setter injection or constructor then how it is happening

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting autowired. You've defined the setter in the class and you are defining the value in the XML config.
To use the autowire feature, you have to explicitly declare it in the class ( with the@Autowired annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the wikipedia definition of Dependency Injection:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection

All spring apps rely on dependency injection in some degree, but Spring does not require autowiring for its implementation.  There are several ways to apply dependency injection:

- Programmatically assemble your beans in a global main program
- Specify your beans in an XML file to be assembled by Spring at startup
- Annotate your bean classes with @Autowired

Each technique achieves the same goal: reduced coupling between components for testability.

The example you provided is the second case, where your bean wirings are specified in an XML file, and loaded into an application context by Spring
on startup.  There are two means of specifying bean properties in XML: setter injection and constructor arguments.  The 'property' tag uses the former, 
the 'constructor-arg' tag the latter.  So your code is relying on XML based setter injection.  If you want autowiring, you should use the @Autowired annotation on
the private fields.  But the code will work the same at runtime, the annotation simply reduces the amount of code you need to write.

You can find more information on the mechanics of bean wiring in the Spring documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

Spring is one of the most well-documented libraries you will find, and I think many more of your questions can be answered there.

Comment: Hey Friends, Thanks a lot for your valuable answers,
Actually I was confused with Autowiring and Dependency Injection.

So to summarize my Answer which I got is, I am using default Dependency Injection feature of Spring here and no Auto Wiring is used in this case, am i correct?


When we use <property> tag so it will by default set the value using setter method and when we use <constructor-arg> then it will set using constructor injection inside <bean> tag.

Explain me If I am understanding wrong....